# Photo app displaying deleted photos in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, photos

Recently I deleted some of my personal photos so that I can hand over it to my younger brother. But all those photos are still appearing in windows 10, I have restarted my PC few times but it is not working. I have checked all my folders and also the onedrive but couldn't find them anywhere. Please help me, I want to remove them ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is related to cache problem and it won't get fixed if you restart your PC. And you will not found these photos in normal folder because they are hidden.

Try these instructions:-

1. Open Run command.
2. Copy-paste this command "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Packages".
3. Go to Microsoft.windowsphotos folder and then to **LocalState > PhotosAppTile** folder.
4. Now delete all photos from that folder.

Credits:- [Buildsometech.com](https://www.buildsometech.com/windows-10-photo-app-showing-deleted-pictures/)

Comment: It really worked. I also found some very old photos in that folder and removed all of them. Then I restarted and nothing is displaying now.

Comment: Happy to hear that!