# Deleted photos still show in recent files and can be viewed in full resolution

Tags: windows, windows-10

I've deleted several photos from my PC, but they still show in Recent Files, displaying the images in full resolution in the photos app when opened *(also shows an error message indicating that the file has been moved or deleted)*, meaning that the data is still being saved somewhere on the disk, and I want to delete it.

- I am not using any kind of cloud backup, this is a local admin account with no associated Microsoft account, and the files are not in the Recycle Bin

I have tried:

- restarting the PC
- uninstalling/reinstalling the Photos app.
- searching for `*.jpg`, which found no relevant results
- searching for the image name, which found several internet explorer shortcuts that cannot be modified or deleted, as well as several Quick Access shortcuts I have deleted, but it seems nothing has changed
- attempting to clear data from:

  ```
  %LocalAppData%\Packages\Microsoft.windows.photos*
  ```

  - As suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1731031/photo-app-displaying-deleted-photos-in-windows-10), I also tried clearing data from `\LocalState\PhotosAppTile`, but there is no data to be deleted, including no hidden files
- I also tried deleting:

  ```
  %LocalAppData%\Packages\Microsoft.windows.photos*
  ```

Comment: 1. Have you emptied Recycle Bin? 2. Do you use cloud storage, e.g., One Drive? 3. Do you have File History enabled? 4. Have you tried utilities such as Wise Disk Cleaner that an clear application MRU's?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Wise disk cleaner removed the files.  I was not able to replicate this immediately after using it, so I still don't know where the files were being saved.  If you post that as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Downvoters- no explanation why?  Surely being able to delete files is useful...

Comment: @Edward Please use correct markdown for `monospaced code` and code boxes - please see the formatting bar or the `?` button on the far right of the formatting bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a specific answer, but has apparently fixed the issue.

Check the nooks and crannies where files might be cached.

1. Empty the *Recycle Bin*. Files deleted there can be restored and accessed.
2. If cloud storage is used, e.g., [Microsoft *OneDrive*](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/onedrive/online-cloud-storage) or [Google *Drive*](https://www.google.com/drive/), delete the files there.
3. If [*Windows Backup*](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/back-up-your-windows-pc-87a81f8a-78fa-456e-b521-ac0560e32338) is enabled, delete the files from there.
4. If [Windows File History](https://www.easeus.com/databackup/file-history-windows-10.html) if enabled, delete the files there.
5. Finally, try using a third-party cleanup utility, such as [Wise Disk Cleaner](https://www.wisecleaner.com/wise-disk-cleaner.html) or an [alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/wise-disk-cleaner/) that can clear application's [MRU lists](https://www.magnetforensics.com/blog/what-is-mru-most-recently-used/) and temporary files in C:\ProgramData, C:\Users<user>\AppData, and other, more obscure locations.

   ##### Caveats:

   Before using a third-party tool, check it at [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload) for malware.

   Carefully check the cleanup utility's settings so that it removes *only* undesired data, and not passwords, intentionally backed-up files, etc.